# Составить рекурентную формулу для A = , при формуле 2nx/(n+1)!

Tags: c#

составить рекурентную формулу для An+1 от формулы An=2nx/(n+1)!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp17
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const double E = 0.001;
            double A, S;
            int n;
            Console.WriteLine("x=");
            double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            S=0;
            n=0;
            A=x;
            do
            {
                S=S+A;
                n=n+1;
                A=A*x*(2*n+1)/((2*n-1)*(n+1)); //пример правильной рекурентной формулы для другой формулы ... x^n*(2n-1)/n!
            }
            while (A>=E);
            Console.WriteLine($"{S}, {n}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: составить рекурентную формулу для An+1 от формулы  An=2nx/(n+1)!

Comment: если в вопросе уже правильная формула - то в чем вопрос? Если неправильная, почему подписана как правильная?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекуррентная формула — формула вида an=f(n,an−1,an−2,…,an−p), выражающая каждый следующий член последовательности an через p предыдущих членов и номер члена последовательности n, вместе с заданными первыми p членами, где p — порядок рекуррентного соотношения.

То есть достаточно вычислить первый член последовательности и вычислить функцию перехода к следующему члену d.

**Рекуррентная формула**

```
An = 2*n*x / (n + 1)!
d = An+1/An = (2*(n + 1)*x*(n + 1)!)/(2*n*x*(n + 2)!)=(n + 1)/(n*n + 2*n)
An+1 = An*d = An*(n + 1)/(n*n + 2*n)
```

**Program.cs**

```
const double e = 0.001d;
Console.WriteLine("x=");
var x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
var s = 0d;
var n = 0;
var a = x;
do
{
    s += a;
    n++;
    a *= ((double)n + 1) / (n * n + 2 * n);
}
while (a >= e);
Console.WriteLine($"{s}, {n}");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Для вычисления используется факториал. Про то, как получить факториал, почитайте [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117617/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c).

После этого, вместо знаменателя дроби в цикле используйте факториал.

Comment: В данном коде не нужно использовать этот метод , нужно просто вывести рекурентную формулу

Comment: @Impossible, в таком случае, это не вопрос кода, а вопрос математической формулы.

_"составить рекурентную формулу для An+1 от формулы An=2nx/(n+1)!"_ - этот вопрос не подразумевает каких-то проблем с C#. Почитайте методички или учебники по этой теме и составьте формулу на бумаге. А затем перенесите её в код.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = x;
...
   n++; 
   A *= n / (n*n-1);
```